# Debian 8 - Update Iptables on boot

Tags: debian, iptables, startup

I am in the process of porting my "configure openvpn server" from ubuntu 14 to debian 8. So far it works well except for this section:

```
# Set up iptables to forward packets for vpn and do this upon startup.
echo 'iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
exit 0' > /etc/rc.local
```

It appears that debian 8 does not use this `/etc/rc.local` file so my vpn server won't forward traffic correctly after a reboot. I have to manually call that script, or execute the commands.

What is the "debian 8 way" for updating the iptables on boot?

---

### Update

After reading that `/etc/rc.local` should work, I made sure the permissions were set to 755 and updated the script to as follows:

```
/bin/echo "starting..." > /root/rc.local.log
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
/bin/echo "completed successfully" >> /root/rc.local.log

exit 0
```

I then created an empty `/root/rc.local.log` and gave it `777` permissions before rebooting. The file remained empty, making me think that the /etc/rc.local script is not being executed at all.

Comment: The question and suggested answer focus more on rc.local than the Debian way to do iptables, perhaps the title should be updated to reflect this.

Comment: @jla, the iptables answer came afterwards and I have just moved that as the correct solution. I do not wish to change the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Debian way of setting up iptables on boot is by using the [iptables-persistent](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/iptables-persistent) package.

Simply install the `iptables-persistent` package, set up the iptables rules like you want them, and then run `netfilter-persistent save`. (Note that the command starts with *`netfilter`* and not *`iptables`*.)

See the [man page for netfilter-persistent](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=netfilter-persistent) for more details.

The method for saving the tables has changes since Debian 7 (Wheezy). In Wheezy one would do something like: `invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent save`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a definitive answer for a Debian 8 way of setting  up `iptables` at boot, but `rc.local` should work.

With systemd, `rc.local` is handled by `/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service`, which is automatically started after the network and runs `/etc/rc.local start`. The only requirement is that `/etc/rc.local` is executable:

```
chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

You also need to have `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the rc.local file for it to execute with systemd, otherwise you will get errors like `Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.local: Exec format error` in red when you run `sudo journalctl`

Comment: I have checked the permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x` and updated the script to use `/sbin/iptables` instead of just `iptables`, but it still wont have changed iptables on reboot (using `sudo iptables -L` to check). Is the rc.local being called too early for iptables commands to be used? Is there a log file for errors when executing rc.local?

Comment: You can view all the logs with `journalctl` (as `root`); search for `iptables` perhaps... Errors appear in red by default.

Comment: Ah I see `Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.local: Exec format error` and `Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.` googling...

Comment: @Programster add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the file

Comment: @roaima, I figured that out and edited the answer before marking it correct. Unfortunately you can't see it yet because its peer review hasnt been accepted yet.